# jmxtrans - Cannot execute

Tags: java, ubuntu, jmxtrans

I am trying to get jmxtrans to work yet I get the below on ubuntu 12.04 and using openjdk 7.

```
/usr/share/jmxtrans# java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

/usr/share/jmxtrans# ./jmxtrans.sh start /var/lib/jmxtrans/kafka.json 
Cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jps -l!
```

What does the above mean?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `jps` file can't be found in the `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin` directory. It is available in the '-devel' packages if you want to install those *(yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel, apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-devel)*. It could also be that your `JAVA_HOME` is not pointing to the correct place if you have multiple java versions installed.

You should not need it however, regular `ps` works fine. You can add a variable to your configuration that says `export USE_JPS=false`. The configuration can be found in `/etc/default/jmxtrans`.

Check out these issues for more information:

https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/issues/89

https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/pull/109